# Windows 8 SDK Platform Toolset missing in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi

I just installed .NET framework 4.5, the Windows 8 SDK, and the Windows 8 DDK on 2 different machines (one at home managed by me, one at work originally setup by IT) both with Visual Studio 2010 Professional SP1 already installed, and both running Window 7 Professional.

I had an old C++/Win32 application in Windows XP that used both the Windows SDK and DDK. I updated it for Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010 project settings.  However, it would not build because some of the SDK/DDK include and library files are new, and it couldn't find them with Platform Toolset set to "v100" in Visual Studio.

Manually adding the Include and Lib folders to the project made it build and run correctly.

Is there some way that I can add the newly installed SDK and DDK to Visual Studio 2010's "Platform Toolset" list?  I thought it was supposed to do this automatically, but neither of the machines I use have it in their list after install and reboot.

Comment: Very big changes in the Win8 SDK, it is not going to consider VS2010 a compatible version of VS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After researching this quite a bit, I finally found a solution.  It doesn't look like it can be added to "Platform Toolset" via any simple method, but at least you don't have to add the paths on every single project you want to use the API.  This worked for me, and allowed me to build Microsoft's "USBView sample application" written for VS2012. The way Microsoft recommends (from the official Microsoft Visual C++ Team blog) is:

For a single project:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/03/25/10287354.aspx
This seems to work with the final SDK release as well.

To apply those settings across multiple projects:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/23/using-the-windows-8-sdk-with-visual-studio-2010-configuring-multiple-projects.aspx