# How to use lacewing project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, shared-libraries, liblacewing

I am a newbie to C++. I want to use, lacewing-project.org in my C++ project. I read the documentation on how to build it and successfully did it using both `DLL - Release` and `Static Library - Release` configurations.

Now I don't know how to use this in my project and how to setup and configure my project? I was following [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87554/Embedding-a-Webserver-in-your-Win32-C-Application), but was stuck in the middle because of missing options in the latest Visual Studio. I use Visual C++ Expression Ed., 2012 on Windows 8

I googled and did the following:

- Added the lib file and the lacewing.h file in my project.
- Under Visual C++ Project Properties, in the Linker folder -> Input I added the lib file as Additional Dependencies.

I placed the dll in Windows\System32 folder. Will I need to do anything with the dll other than placing it in win32 folder?

My code is from the [hello world example](https://github.com/udp/lacewing/blob/master/examples/hello_world/hello_world.cc) given in the documentation.

When I try to compile I get:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__lw_version referenced in function "void __cdecl on_get(struct lacewing::_webserver *,struct lacewing::_webserver_request *)" (?on_get@@YAXPAU_webserver@lacewing@@PAU_webserver_request@2@@Z)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl lacewing::pump_delete(struct lacewing::_pump *)" (__imp_?pump_delete@lacewing@@YAXPAU_pump@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct lacewing::_error * __thiscall lacewing::_eventpump::start_eventloop(void)" (__imp_?start_eventloop@_eventpump@lacewing@@QAEPAU_error@2@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) struct lacewing::_eventpump * __cdecl lacewing::eventpump_new(void)" (__imp_?eventpump_new@lacewing@@YAPAU_eventpump@1@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl lacewing::_stream::writef(char const *,...)" (__imp_?writef@_stream@lacewing@@QAAXPBDZZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl on_get(struct lacewing::_webserver *,struct lacewing::_webserver_request *)" (?on_get@@YAXPAU_webserver@lacewing@@PAU_webserver_request@2@@Z)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall lacewing::_webserver::host(long)" (__imp_?host@_webserver@lacewing@@QAEXJ@Z) referenced in function _main
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall lacewing::_webserver::on_get(void (__cdecl*)(struct lacewing::_webserver *,struct lacewing::_webserver_request *))" (__imp_?on_get@_webserver@lacewing@@QAEXP6AXPAU12@PAU_webserver_request@2@@Z@Z) referenced in function _main
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) struct lacewing::_webserver * __cdecl lacewing::webserver_new(struct lacewing::_pump *)" (__imp_?webserver_new@lacewing@@YAPAU_webserver@1@PAU_pump@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl lacewing::webserver_delete(struct lacewing::_webserver *)" (__imp_?webserver_delete@lacewing@@YAXPAU_webserver@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\Jayarathina\Desktop\New folder (3)\test\Debug\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Please help...

Comment: Which lib file did you add as an additional dependency?

Comment: >The lib that was generated when lacewing-project was compiled using "Static Library - Release". No other libs other than that

Comment: > And the dll was the one that was generated when compiled with DLL - Release

Comment: If you compile the library statically, you need to `#define lw_import` before including `lacewing.h` to strip the function prototypes of `__declspec(dllimport)`. You won't need a DLL if you link statically.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin I am really sorry to disturb you, but I think I am doing something wrong.. :( Adding `#define lw_import` line before `#include "lacewing.h"` gives me 31 unresolved externals http://i.imgur.com/WCqTZc4.jpg

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin And just for your reference, the project properties: http://i.imgur.com/bxCPjaD.jpg

Comment: That's the library dependencies.  Because you're linking statically, you'll need to link them in yourself (as of 0.5.1, that's `ws2_32.lib mswsock.lib mpr.lib secur32.lib crypt32.lib`).

Comment: wow... that worked. Just that you know, these lib files are present in `C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\win8\um\x86` for x86 Windows 8 machine... I request you to post your replies as answer below. Thanks a lot for your time. I really appreciate it. And thanks for your wonderful product.

Comment: Done. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link statically with the library, one must define `lw_import`. If you don't do this, it will default to `__declspec(dllimport)`:

```
#ifndef lw_import
   #define lw_import __declspec (dllimport)
#endif
```

which causes the linker to try and pull the functions in from a DLL (which is wrong when statically linking). To do this, you can either add `lw_import=` to your preprocessor definitions in the project properties, or `#define` it before including `lacewing.h`, as so:

```
#define lw_import
#include <lacewing.h>
```

As you're statically linking the library, you will also need to link any library dependencies into your own project.  You can find the list in the project properties of `liblacewing.vcproj` itself, but as of 0.5.1 these are `ws2_32.lib`, `mswsock.lib`, `mpr.lib`, `secur32.lib` and `crypt32.lib`.

Comment: For those who are wondering where to get the lib files on Windows 8, they are present in `C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\win8\um\x86` more info on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14778492/960641